# How to access openoffice.org database from command line

Tags: sql, command-line, cygwin, hsqldb, openoffice-base

I have a database built in openoffice.org base (.odb).  I would like to open this database using a command line sql client, such as sqlite3 or psql.  Can anyone tell me how to make this work? I am running Windows 7 64-bit and have cygwin installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't access the odb database **directly**, since it's an embedded db instance. But you can migrate the odb to a "normal" [hsqldb database](http://hsqldb.org/) and run it in a HSQLDB server. After that, the database will be accessible using command line clients like [SQLTool](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch08.html). You still can access that database from OpenOffice Base using JDBC, so you can continue using the data from OpenOffice as well as access it "from outside".

The odb is a zip file containing the standard hsqldb database files, so it shouldn't be too hard to make it available to hsqldb directly. There are some guides and tutorials how to proceed:

- [How to open an OOo database directly with HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/web/openofficetips.html)
- [HyperSQL with OpenOffice.org](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/openoffice-app.html)
- [OOo forum](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?p=386995#386995)
- [another OOo forum entry](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=102514)
- [... and a third one](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=94068)